# which Xeon CPU series is better?

Tags: central-processing-unit, xeon

I tried to read the series number?

There are 5600, 5500,E3,E7, 7500, 3400, Opteron 6000, Opteron 4000 etc

So which one is  better?

And within each series, is that the higher the number the better? for example, E5506 is better than E5504 and E7520 must be better than E550x?

Comment: Basic research - Xeon != Opteron.

Comment: It is funny how people today deciding on server hardware can not even come up with a basic corect question, isn't it ;)

Comment: maybe. Things like model numbers and product families can be pretty confusing though. Particularly on cpus and graphics cards.

Answer (score 2):

It's, unfortunately, not as simple as just "better". Some CPUs, for example, may have more powerful cores but fewer of them. So single-threaded tasks perform better on them but tasks that can take advantage of multiple cores don't. You can get a basic idea of the raw horsepower of a CPU by taking a look at its [PassMark CPU rating](http://www.cpubenchmark.net/high_end_cpus.html).